# Is Firefox 57 multithreaded?

Tags: firefox, cpu, multi-threaded, firefox-57

According to [Multiprocess Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) on MDN, Firefox 57 finally runs things in different processes.

So is Firefox 57 multithreaded?

In particular, how many cores does it use at most? Say I open 20 tabs at once on a quad-core machine, will Firefox 57 launch as many threads, or at least as many as needed to max out my CPU?

(Chromium for instance spawns a number of sub-processes and very easily uses all the resources available. Firefox up to 56 in GNU/Linux is rarely seen going over 135 % of one core however many tabs I open.)

Comment: It uses as many cores as your system has.  135% of a code that must be a typo

Comment: @Ramhound not really - both Linux and Mac OS report a single core as 100%, so 135% utilisation is for example 100% of one core and 35% of another.

Comment: Currently using 7 processes on my octa-core system... running 4 instances of http://browserbench.org/ARES-6 uses about 45-50% of the system (and causes the browser to lag a bit), so it uses 3-4 cores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Is Firefox 57 multithreaded?

Yes, and it is configurable as well.

> You may see 3 or more processes running in the Task Manager
>
> - one process for the main Firefox window (user interface)
> - one or more processes for content threads set via "Options/Preferences -> General -> Performance"
>     (dom.ipc.processCount), default in 57 is 4.
> - one process for the compositor thread (Windows)
> - one process for Quantum CSS (Stylo)

Source [Why is Firefox Quantum running 7 instances?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1185037)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Change how many processes multi-process Firefox uses](https://www.ghacks.net/2016/02/15/change-how-many-processes-multi-process-firefox-uses/)
- ["E10S-Multi:" A new multi-process model for Firefox](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/06/firefox-54-e10s-webextension-apis-css-clip-path/)

Comment: Thanks, so the default is up to 7?

Comment: @Nemo Yes. That is the default.